# copy data from form feild in django to a variable

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

model.py

```
 class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    mail = models.EmailField()
```

view.py

```
def create(request):
  if request.POST:
    form = ClientForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        subject = form.cleaned_data['name']
        mail = form.cleaned_data['mail']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
        form = ClientForm()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form

   return render_to_response('save.html', args)


 html


<form action="/create/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
    {{ form}}
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Client">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here i successfully created a form and save the data to db. but i like to sent a mail to the client also. how do get the email directly from the form

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're already getting the email into the `mail` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your view code you've got the form data available already, `mail = form.cleaned_data['mail']` gives you the email address (if you do a print form.cleaned_data you'll see in your console all the form data.